# How to convert date from "Oct 01 20:00" to "Oct 1 20:00" format (space padded)?

Tags: shell-script, date

Here `Oct 01` has to be printed as `Oct  1` i.e without 0. I need two spaces between Oct and 1 i.e like `Oct  1`.

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Sobrique, what is an "XY problem"?

Comment: It means that perhaps you don't really need to format your date like this, but you think you do.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/270186

Answer (score 9):

With GNU `date`:

```
date -d "Oct 01 20:00" "+%b %_d %k:%M"
```

Where:

- `%b`: locale's abbreviated month name (e.g., Jan)
- `%_d`: day of month (space padded )
- `%k`: hour ( 0..23)
- `%M`: minute (00..59)

Ouput:

```
Oct  1 20:00
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I know `-d` is not POSIX, but relatively common. However, that's why I upvoted your answer as the more portable one.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for `POSIXLY_CORRECT` I will have a look at this. And instead `%_d`, `%e` can be used which is in posix: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/date.html#tag_04_33_05_01

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert those strings when found in some text, and only when they follow that specific `Mmm dd HH:MM` pattern, on a GNU or FreeBSD  system (and derivatives), you could do:

```
sed -E "s/($(locale abmon|tr ';' '|')) 0([0-9] [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])/\1  \2/g"
```

It takes the list of month name abbreviations from the output of `locale abmon` so that adapts to the localisation preference of the caller. Use `LC_ALL=C locale abmon` to force English month name abbreviations.